# Condicional en SUM (mysql)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo la tabla `factura_habitaciones`, donde se ingresan las reservas de habitaciones que posteriormente voy a facturar.

Quiero calcular el total de todos los registros en la tabla con una sola sentencia en MySQL teniendo en cuenta que

1. los días se multiplican por el precio de la habitación
2. El costo del huesped adicional es de **50000** a partir de los 5
   huespedes (es decir a partir de `numero_huespedes > 4`, ya que los 4
   primeros no cuestan)

El total es el punto 1) sumado a el punto 2)

Cómo hago para que con la siguiente sentencia me calcule a partir del `huesped #5 (>4)`:

```
SELECT SUM( precio_habitacion * dias ) + SUM( numero_huespedes *50000 )
FROM facturacion
```

***pd:*** el `where numero_huespedes > 4` al final no sirve ya que no calcularia el `precio_habitacion * dias` cuando no se cumpla la condición

[image: factura_hab]

Comment: Agregué una respuesta usando el IF Statement. Te adjunto la documentación para que la veas :) https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es fácil. Usando IF, THEN, ELSE. [Ver documentación:](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php)

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera, pasaría de ser:

```
SELECT SUM( precio_habitacion * dias ) + SUM( numero_huespedes *50000 )
FROM facturacion
```

A ser:

```
IF numero_huespedes>4 
THEN SELECT SUM( precio_habitacion * dias ) + SUM( numero_huespedes *50000) as Ingreso FROM facturacion
ELSE SELECT SUM( precio_habitacion * dias ) + SUM( numero_huespedes *precio_normal) as Ingreso FROM facturacion
END IF;
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta +1

Answer (score 2):

Prueba del modo siguiente tu consulta

```
SELECT id, SUM(precio_habitacion * dias) + SUM(numero_huespedes * 50000) AS Costo
FROM hotel
WHERE numero_huespedes > 4
GROUP BY id;
```

Al final lo único que agregué fue agrupar los resultados por `id` y en el `where` le indico que haga las multiplicaciones y sumas solo donde la cantidad de huéspedes sea `>4`

Estoy usando el `GROUP BY` al final de mi consulta por que en el primer renglón estoy usando dos funciones de agrupación que son  `SUM()`

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[link al ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d0d85c5a858fba4c5f720ce48da0862)

Comment: Gracias por comentar, el problema de ese where al final es que solo se hace la operación cuando hay más de 4 huespedes, yo necesito sacar el calculo en todos los casos, si hay 4 huespedes o menos que se calcule precio_habitacion * dias (ignorando los huespedes), por otra parte si hay más de 4 se calcula los huespedes excedentes * 50000 + (precio_habitacion * dias), gracias